# AmazonEC2- Can an EC2 account be created programmatically?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I've searched through Amazon EC2's API documentation, but I haven't seen an API to create/modify/remove an Amazon EC2 account programmatically. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,
Mauricio

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about creating new Amazon's user for EC2, it is not possible to do programmatically. As in any website registration it requires human interaction. Particularly you will need to provide credit card etc. I also was not able to find a way to create new set of credentials programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

What is the overall problem you're trying to solve? Are you trying to create an AWS account? Or simply create a new set of credentials for accessing EC2?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create accounts programmatically, but depending exactly on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to use AWS [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) which allows you to create credentials with restricted access (so for example an user can list current instances, but not start or destroy them)